# Merging of two dataframes generates less rows in the final dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I want to merge two data frames so that the rows of `df2` are transformed into columns of `df1`.

```
df1 = 

ID   B
1    3
2    4
3    5

df2 = 
ID   Value
1    ABC
1    ACD
2    WWW
```

The result should be:

```
result = 
    ID   B   A_1   A_2
    1    3   ABC   ACD
    2    4   WWW   NaN
    3    5   NaN   NaN
```

The problem is that after merging I miss some rows in `df1` in my real dataset, while I want to keep all rows of `df1` even if there is no matching in `df2`.

```
df2['col'] = 'A_' + df2.groupby(['ID'])['Value'].cumcount().astype(str)
df2 = df2.pivot(index='ID', columns='col', values='Value').reset_index()
result = pd.merge(df1, df2)
```

**Dimensions:**

```
df1 = 1404659 rows
df2 = 1015639 rows
result = 1216773 rows (!!!)
```

What might be the reason that the merging of two dataframes generates less rows in the dataframe `result`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you need `left` join, because by default `inner` join in [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html):

```
result = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='left')
```

Another solution is use [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) with default `left` join:

```
result = df1.join(df2)
```